# How to call a non-static method in an imported project (from another non-static method) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, static-methods

Sorry, I know there is a lot of info on this but couldn't find any that pertain to calling from non-static method to another non-static method in another project. Here is my issue:

I imported an existing project and added the reference.

I am able to call static methods in the imported project.

But I cannot call non-static methods.

I am calling from a non-static method.

I don't want to change the method in the imported project to static because then I think I will have trouble calling other non-static methods from that program.

Usually calling a non-static method from another non-static method is not a problem. I don't understand why calling a non-static method in an imported project will cause a problem.

Can someone suggest how I can do it? Do I have to create a new object? For example I had a go and tried:

```
 Form newForm= new MyImportedProject.MyNonStaticMethod();
```

But there were not methods in newForm to call.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create object of the class which containing method you want and then you can call the public methods like below

```
var obj =  new MyImportedProject.MyImportedClass();
obj.MyPublicMethod1();
obj.MyPublicMethod2()
```

Or

```
new MyImportedProject.MyImportedClass().MyPublicMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of a non-static class first.
As per your example, try:

```
var myImportedProject = new MyImportedProject();
Form newForm = myImportedProject.MyNonStaticMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of the class Like

```
MyImportedProject.ClassName nclass=new MyImportedProject.ClassName();
```

new you will have access to the public members of this class

```
MyClass.Method()
```